# No WebApplication provider is present

Tags: eclipse, maven, jersey, servlet-3.0

`pom.xml` is facing this error:

```
com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: No WebApplication provider is present
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.WebApplicationFactory.createWebApplication(WebApplicationFactory.java:69)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.create(ServletContainer.java:392)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.create(ServletContainer.java:307)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:603)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:374)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:557)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

XML:

```
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.ayan.resapi</groupId>
    <artifactId>RestAPI</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>RestAPI Jersey Webapp</name>
    <build>
        <finalName>RestAPI</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Run the application using "mvn embedded-glassfish:run" -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${glassfish.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <goalPrefix>embedded-glassfish</goalPrefix>
                    <app>D:/Workspace/Eclipse-JSP/Eclipse_Maven/target/${project.build.finalName}.war</app>
                    <autoDelete>true</autoDelete>
                    <port>8080</port>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
                        <version>${project.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>1.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-web</artifactId>
            <version>${glassfish.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency> <groupId> org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId> <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId> 
            </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>1.20-SNAPSHOT</jersey.version>
        <glassfish.version>3.1.1</glassfish.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

`web.xml`:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container, 
         see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation /latest/jax-rs.html#d4e194 -->
    <web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class> com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
                <param-value>com.ayan.resapi.RestAPI</param-value>
            </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

`MyResouces.java`:

```
package com.ayan.resapi.RestAPI;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

/** Example resource class hosted at the URI path "/myresource"
 */
@Path("/myresource")
public class MyResource {

    /** Method processing HTTP GET requests, producing "text/plain" MIME media
     * type.
     * @return String that will be send back as a response of type "text/plain".
     */
    @GET 
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String getIt() {
        return "Hi there!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you have 2 different version of `com.sun.jersey` in your `pom.xml`. Try to remove below one as `1.17` version of different jersey library is  present in the pom file and there may be chances of mismatch of version.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version> 
</dependency>
```

Comment: I did but still I am facing this issue:

Comment: SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: No WebApplication provider is present
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.WebApplicationFactory.createWebApplication(WebApplicationFactory.java:69)....

Comment: can you also update the `jersey-client` version to  `1.17`. It should be same as jersey-servlet. ?